# Should I Protect function's options

Tags: options, symbols

I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to protect symbols within a package (a function's options in particular) so that no other value can be assigned to it.

Consider a function `myFunc`:

```
Options[myFunc, OptionsPattern[]] = {op1->5}
myFunc[x_] :=
  Module[{},
    (* Function's core implementation *)
    Print[OptionValue[op1]+2];
  ]
```

If I leave it as is, `op1` is unprotected and anyone can assign a value to it.
That doesn't seem to affect `myFunc`'s functionality, but seems perhaps unprofessional (?).

Checking the symbol `PlotRange`, for instance, turns out protected, as it is an option for `Plot[]` and `ListPlot[]`.

Up until now I've been protecting my options with (right before `myFunc`'s definition):

```
Unprotect[op1]; 
op1 = op1;
Protect[op1];
```

I must've seen that somewhere, because I don't remember coming up with it. Apart from the self definition `op1=op1`, I understand it, but I'm curious to what the "correct" way to do it would be. And also, do I even need to protect it? Or is it just for clarity for the user (and other package makers), saying "Hey, this symbol is an option! Don't get it confused with your variables.".

EDIT:
I forgot to mention. I'm also writing documentation for this application, in Wolfram Workbench. So, it's useful to have well defined protected symbols in general that I can document.

Comment: If your function `myFunc` and its options form a part of a package that you will publicly release, then I certainly would recommend `Protect`ing it.  If its something you will use on your own, it's up to you -- do you have a tendency to forget your option names, and assign values to them?

Comment: Indeed not a at all. I do forget their name, but I don't use them as variables. I usually write them with first capital letter, like `Op1` (forgot to do so in example),  and I write my variables with lowercase letter, so there's very little chance for collision

Comment: You put `OptionsPattern[]` in `Options[]` instead of `myFunc` in your example code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Protect` *everything* from the package's context, unless it is explicitly meant to be set by the package's users*.  It doesn't matter if the symbol is an option or not.

```
BeginPackage["Foo`"];

Unprotect["Foo`*"];

(* list all symbols meant for export,
   including any symbols used as options only *)

Begin["`Private`"];

(* package code *)

With[{syms = Names["Foo`*"]},
  SetAttributes[syms, {Protected, ReadProtected}]
];    

End[];

EndPackage[];
```

I agree with @Henrik that it is good practice to use strings for option names to limit name pollution (and reduce the chance of name conflicts), especially if the option will be used with a single function only.

It is true that if you use the Workbench documentation tools, then it will not be possible to have a separate documentation page for a string option. But should you have one?  I prefer to document options in the doc page of the function they belong to—except when the same option is used by several functions with the very same meaning.

---

<sup>* Even then it's probably better to have the settable symbol protected and overload `Set` for it—that way you can have error checking for its value.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for this contributions.In most of my cases the option is only for that function. Indeed documenting the option in the docpage of the function is better. I don't really check the doc pages for options themselves that often, specially given the option only works for that function.

Comment: BTW, I think `SetAttributes[#, {Protected, ReadProtected}] & /@ Names["MArthur\`*"];` can be used to protect all symbols and avoids making `syms` a symbol as well.

Comment: @A.Vieira You're right, it should have come before the `End[]`. The pure function version works too, also with `@` instead of `/@`.

Answer (score 4):

I always use strings as the names for the options (like `"op1"` instead of `op1`). You cannot overwrite a string. That's good! For some weird reason, you can still use the "unstringfied" version `op1` as in `myFunc[bla,op1->2]`. Of course, `myFunc[bla,"op1"->2]` is also valid. So, you get safety even without `Protect`ion and still you are not forced to type many quotes.

Comment: The only thing that annoys me about string options is that I cannot use `Information[]` on them. Otherwise, this is a good suggestion.